# How to read a downloaded rds file

Tags: r

In 12.5 of this textbook (["R Programming for Data Science" by Roger D. Peng](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/managing-data-frames-with-the-dplyr-package.html)) , it tells me to download the city of Chicago database ( a link is provided. Then it says "After unzipping the archive, you can load the data into R using the readRDS() function.

```
chicago <- readRDS("chicago.rds")"
```

And I unzipped the file in my downloads folder and then typed in the code (`chicago <- readRDS("chicago.rds")`) just like it says. Yet it is not working and I keep getting an error message saying:

> Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In gzfile(file, "rb") :
>     cannot open compressed file 'chicago.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

So how do I actually load this data in/unzip it?
I am brand new to R and really need to get this file unzipped and loaded so I can continue with my work!

Comment: As is, R assumes that `"chicago.rds"` is in your working directory. I think it is a good practice to always include absolute paths. However, if you want to keep it as-is, start by checking the location of your working directory `getwd()`. And, if it is not in the same location as `"chicago.rds"`, move the file or move your working directory `setwd()`. Hope this helps! My advice would be to include the full path in your `readRDS()` statement whether or not it is in your current working directory.

Comment: I am brand new to R is there any way you could dumb this down? And by pathway, you mean to put in the file path? Maybe put in an example for me?

Comment: R is looking for the file, and it can't find it. If you just include the file name it looks in its "home" on your computer. Home = your working directory in R. It is a better practice to include the full file path rather than rely on your working directory. E.g., if it were on my desktop the full path would be `"C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/my_file.rds"` rather than `"my_file.rds"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can `readRDS` (i.e. read RDS file) only from your current working directory. To check your current work directory use command `getwd()`.

Please note down the path where you are unpacking and read it from there by giving complete path to the unzipped file. Like if the file is present inside subfolder inside a folder then the give complete path like:

```
chicago <- readRDS("/folder/subfolder/chicago.rds")
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up your working directory to the folder where you have downloaded the Chicago file. Then, just code `chicago <- readRDS('chicago')`. Hope this helped!

Comment: By set up my working directory do you mean place the file in whatever file the getwd() funciton tells me I am working in?

Comment: There is a Files tab on the bottom right. Then, navigate the folders to the folder you will be working out of/where the Chicago file is located. Click the "More" dropdown button, and there should be an option saying "Set As Working Directory"! It is better to have a distinct folder for different projects so there are clear paths to work with.

Comment: Did not work, because the file is still compressed, even though I extracted all

Comment: Why would it still be compressed? I thought you unzipped the file. The new file that pops up is the file you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setwd() to set the directory where is the file. For example 
setwd("C:/Users/name/Desktop")